# MySQL: Trigger to Insert New Row in One Table When Another Table has a Row Inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I would like to INSERT a new row into an existing table, when the row is INSERTED into another table.  There are tons of examples, of this, however I am not able to find one with a trigger.  Here is my code.  What am I doing wrong?  The trigger is simply not firing:

```
USE `MTFDFormdB`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `StationTrouble_temp` 
AFTER INSERT ON `StationTrouble_temp` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `StationTrouble`
(`_rowid_`,
`fullname`,
`username`,
`email5`,
`controlnumber`,
`station`,
`problemdescription`,
`appaerentcause`,
`observed`,
`reportstatus`,
`_submitted_`,
`_fromaddress_`,
`_flags_`,
`_transactid_`,
`submittername`,
`other submitter`) SELECT rowid_,
fullname,
username,
email5,
controlnumber,
station,
problemdescription,
appaerentcause,
observed,
reportstatus,
_submitted_,
_fromaddress_,
_flags_,
_transactid_,
submittername,othersubmitter
FROM StationTrouble_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new` keyword to get the newly inserted record from the table where the trigger is executed, so it should be as

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `StationTrouble_temp` AFTER INSERT ON `StationTrouble_temp` 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `StationTrouble`
        (
                `_rowid_`,
                `fullname`,
                `username`,
                `email5`,
                `controlnumber`,
                `station`,
                `problemdescription`,
                `appaerentcause`,
                `observed`,
                `reportstatus`,
                `_submitted_`,
                `_fromaddress_`,
                `_flags_`,
                `_transactid_`,
                `submittername`,
                `othersubmitter`
        )
        values
        (
            new.rowid_,
            new.fullname,
            new.username,
            new.email5,
            new.controlnumber,
            new.station,
            new.problemdescription,
            new.appaerentcause,
            new.observed,
            new.reportstatus,
            new._submitted_,
            new._fromaddress_,
            new._flags_,
            new._transactid_,
            new.submittername,
            new.othersubmitter
        );
end ; $$
```